# UserName in _Layout.cshtml in DotNet Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, identity, claims

In my Login post controller I am setting claims like

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("userName", "Jhon"));
        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "userData");
        var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
HttpContext.User = userPrincipal;
```

and in _Layout.cshtml page I am getting null

```
Context.User.Identities.Count == 0
```

Please help

Comment: While im not entirely sure if thats a viable way to use identity i dont think that is the correct way. I would sugest looking up the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I am also setting `HttpContext.User` in `AccountCotroller` and when I redirect to Home I get zero count in `HttpContext.User.identity.Claims`